# ag-grid disable checkbox programatically via gridOptions API

Tags: ag-grid

I have a column with `checkboxSelection=true`

Under some conditions and via the API, I would like to decide whether the checkbox is readonly, i.e., I can't check/uncheck.

Is this possible?

Comment: so you want to disable row selection for certain rows as well? or just the ability to use the checkbox to select a row?

Comment: disable row selection for certain rows as well - make these rows "readonly" for selection

Comment: is there any recommended solution available to the above problem ?

Comment: For future reference, here is complete info on [disabling checkbox in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012540/7977581).

Answer (score 8):

If someone is still looking for an answer for this,
I found a simple solution,

in your `gridOptions` add the following

```
gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
  {
    checkboxSelection: true,
    cellStyle: params => 
      params.value === 'YOUR_VALUE' ?  
          {'pointer-events': 'none'}
          : ''
   }
 ]  
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Additionally if you are changing this dynamically you need to refreshCells

Answer (score 3):

For those still looking for an answer:

- use `isRowSelectable` in gridConfig
- set `showDisabledCheckboxes: true` in column defs

Answer (score 2):

The property **checkboxSelection** can either be a boolean OR a function.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#gsc.tab=0

By using a function you can show or hide the checkbox row-based:

```
checkboxSelection = function(params) {
   // add your cancheck-logic here
   if (params.data.yourProperty) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Disabling a checkbox is not possible out of the box. One possible way is to reset the checkbox back to it's original state:

```
onRowSelected:(params) => {
    if(params.data.yourProperty && params.node.isSelected())
        params.node.setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: Alexander, thanks!
My intention was to disable it and not to hide it - as some of my check-boxes are checked but cannot be unchecked...

Comment: Alexander, I need to disable the checkbox component as in "disabled=true"
In the enterprise edition there's a "functionsReadOnly=true" in the tool-panel that completely disable it - you can see the example here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel/#example-read-only
this is what I need

Comment: Aviram, did you ever get this to work on an individual row?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using checkboxSelection=true, you can try cellRenderer

```
  field: 'isMandatory',
  cellRenderer: (params) => {
       if (params.value) {
          return `<input type="checkbox" checked/>`;
       }
       else {
          return `<input type="checkbox" />`;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation, you can you isRowSelectable in your gridConfig

```
    isRowSelectable: function(rowNode) {
        return rowNode.data ? rowNode.data.condition: false;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

isRowSelectable does not work in single selection mode.
Better to disable it using css

cellClassRules:
{
'checkbox-disabled': isCheckboxDisabled ,
}